# Insert data into database table using parameters for columns names

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to insert data into table using SP. But I have database table column name in parameters. I want to use parameters as column in SP to insert data. You have any idea to insert data through column name as parameter.

```
cmd3.Connection = conn;
cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd3.CommandText = "CustomerInfoProcedure";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col0", Col0);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col1", Col1);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col2", Col2); 

//insert query using in SP, but its give error 
insert into #AgentDetails (@Col0, @Col1, @Col2)
values (@eCol0, @eCol1, @eCol2);
```

Comment: You can't parametrise a column name, you would have to use **secure** dynamic SQL, but this sounds like an XY problem. Why do you want to specify the columns? What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Larnu Because the order of column is changing. I am doing mapping b/w table column and excel column. So the order of table column can be change. Hope u understand

Comment: Why does the order of the columns in the table matter? `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Col1,Col2,Col3) VALUES('abc','def','hij');` and `INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable(Col3, Col1, Col2) VALUES('hij','abc','def');` are semantically identically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge (although I haven't worked with SQL Server for a while) you can't really do that directly. If you insist on having it this way, you have a couple of (bad) options:

- Use `sp_executesql` and build your query dynamically by concatenating relevant strings ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)). This approach will likely result in fairly slow queries (since they can't be optimized before they are generated) and has huge security downsides (think SQL injection).
- Have a set of prepared queries inside your SP that cover all possible combinations of the input parameters. This will alleviate performance and security concerns, but it will leave you (depending on the number of field combinations you want to have) with a huge and complicated code in your SP that will be hard to maintain.

**UPD:**

After seeing your comment: in your case it will be much better to handle column reordering in the code and only have a single signature for the SP. E.g.

```
var value0 = Col0 == "field0" ? eCol0 : Col1 == "field0" ? eCol1 : eCol2;
var value1 = ...

cmd3.Connection = conn;
cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd3.CommandText = "CustomerInfoProcedure";
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value0", value0);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", value1);
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", value2); 

//insert query using in SP
insert into #AgentDetails (field0, field1, field2)
values (@value0, @value1, @value2);
```

**UPD2**

If you have a large number of variables, then similar approach would work as long as all the values and column-field mapping are stored in appropriate data structures. E.g. let's say that you have an array of column names in the order they follow in your spreadsheet, e.g. taken from a spreadsheet header:

```
string[] columnsNames; // ["field1", "field2", "field10", "field0", ...]
```

, an array of values that you need to insert, per row, at the same order as the columnsNames:

```
string[] values; // ["value1", "value2", "value10", "value0", ...]
```

and an array where the column names are listed in the order they need to be in for your SP parameters:

```
// This list can be made into a constant, but you need
// to keep it in sync with the SP signature
string[] parameterOrder = ["field0", "field1", "field2", ...];
```

In this case you can use logic like this one to add your data right into the correct place:

```
// This dictionary will be used for field position lookups
var columnOrderDict = new Dictionary<string, int>(); 
for (var i = 0; i < columnsNames.Length; i++)
{
    columnOrderDict[columnsNames[i]] = i;   
}

cmd3.Connection = conn;
cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd3.CommandText = "CustomerInfoProcedure";

for (var j = 0; j < parameterOrder.Length; j++)
{
    var currentFieldName = parameterOrder[j];
    if (columnOrderDict.ContainsKey(currentFieldName))
    {
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue(currentFieldName, values[columnOrderDict[currentFieldname]]);
    } else {
        cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue(currentFieldName, DBNull.Value);
    }
}
```

This code is built on multiple assumptions, such as that the column headers in your spreadsheet will exactly match the stored procedure parameter names etc, but I hope it should give you enough of a hint to build your own logic.

Also don't forget proper validation - currently the only thing this code guards against is the situation when a field that's needed by SP is missing from the input data. You also need to validate data format, the number of values should match the number of headers etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir. your answer is working for me but this is not only for 3 values it can vary till 40-50. In that case how can we do. Please update the answer with this new query.

Comment: @scoop My answer was based on the variables you had in your original question. I assume you don't have 40-50 separate variables for the field values, right? I will add an example that assumes some things regarding the input data (such as that you have them in some array or list-like structure).

Comment: Thanks sir. You are amazing and helpful. Thanks alot again

Comment: @scoop You're welcome! If my answer is answering your question fully, could you please mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: Can u tell me, how will we store data into db using SP.

Comment: @scoop Your question is a bit generic, could you explain more? You already have `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(...)` in your original code, which is basically what's usually needed to save the data into db.